# Envers: How to get a set of revisions and revision objects in one query

Tags: hibernate-envers

I need to generate a report (a table) based in the log information that Envers provides, to shows to the user, a list of changes of an object. Something like this (taking a User entity as example):

```
Id | field        | old_value | new_value
1  | display_name | Boby77    | Boby
1  | display_name | Boby      | Bob
1  | age          | 21        | 22
```

The way I found is below:

1. Get the object type and ID and use method AuditReader.getResivions(). This to get the list of revisions of that object (numbers only).
2. Iterate over the revisions list and get the older versions of the object by calling AuditReader.find(User.class, 1L, i), and put everyone of those objects in a Map called revObjects.
3. Iterate over to compare the object properties (between revisions) to find the property changes, so I can get the old value, and the new value.

This will work, however, I think it does too much queries, as I suppose that, every AuditReader.find() operation will perform as a minimum 1 query over database.
It would be very nice if I can get all the object versions in one query, something like .getRevisionsWithObjects().

I reviewed the AuditQuery class, with the hope to find some solution, and found that this class works only in the scope of a revision, I mean, all the supported queries run over a given revision only.

Does anybody knows about How to get a set of revisions and revision objects in one query?

Any suggestion helps, thank you

Comment: Did you come up with any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I queried for audit history of a single entity. 
The AuditHistory class is a wrapper that brings together my custom RevisionEntity and the Entity that is audited.

```
List<AuditHistory<T>> auditHistoryList = new ArrayList<AuditHistory<T>>();
AuditQuery auditQuery = getAuditReader().createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(getEntityClass(), false, false).add(AuditEntity.id().eq(entity.getId()));
for (Object queryResults: auditQuery.getResultList()) {
    auditHistoryList.add(new AuditHistory<T>((Object[])queryResults));
};
return auditHistoryList;
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling on this thread, ENVERs enables the ability to retrieve the historical entities only (without the metadata) via the first boolean below (note the "true" value).

```
AuditQuery auditQuery = getAuditReader()
   .createQuery()
   .forRevisionsOfEntity(getEntityClass(), true, false)
   .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(entity.getId()));

 return auditQuery.getResultList();
```